# Update value in a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I create a list of identical dictionaries and I would like to update only **the value of one specific key of one of the dictionaries of the list**, but I don't get what I expect.

[Code trial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxDnk.png)

Would you know how to do that?

Comment: Please share the code instead of a img

Comment: *there is only one distinct dictionary object in your list*, that is how the `*` operator works with lists. In the future, please post all code as formatted text in the question itself. See [this link for how to format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: when you multiply your list like you did in the initialization, you are receiving the same reference n times, that's why you are overriding all of your entries